# I want to get Ids in the label when selecting the picker view data

Tags: ios

When selecting I was able to get the data in picker view. But my Requirement is when I select the Data from picker view I want to get the Id of the specific data in the label. Here is the below code :

```
if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                           options:0 error:&error];
        if(!entries)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
        }
        else{

        for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
            projID = [entries valueForKey:@"ID_PROJECT"];
           projectNames = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
        }
             NSLog(@"projID : %@", projID);
            _projectpicker.delegate = self;
            _projectpicker.dataSource = self;
        }

    }       else {

    }
```

**ProjId : (1,
2,
3,
4,
5
)**

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *myArrayString = [projID description];
    lblProjects.text = myArrayString;
    lblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    lblSubTasks.text = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];

}
```

My Problem is I want to load the **ProId** in `lblProjects.text`.

Thanks in Advance
Kiran Kumar

Comment: Why aren't you using `entries[row]`?

Comment: I was very new to this IOS so I dont know how to do that

Comment: What are `projID`, `taskNames`, `subtaskNames`?

Comment: ProjID consists of Project ID that was coming from Database (webservice) Tasknames and subtasknames were data loading in the rspective fields and all were NSArrays

Answer (score 0):

Just store `entries`. As an array it provides an easily indexable list of content for the picker, and the dictionaries it contains can be used to populate the picker rows. When the reo is selected you can use exactly the same content:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSDictionary *rowDict = entries[row];

    lblProjects.text = rowDict[@"ID_PROJECT"];
    lblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    lblSubTasks.text = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
}
```

it isn't currently clear where all of the data displayed in the picker is coming from, but using the `entries` array directly should solve a number of potential issues.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Response Wain But I had 3 components in the picker view and other thing is Projects, tasks and sub tasks will load in the viewDidload Method itself. So Do u have any other suggestion?

Comment: Show how you're setting up the picker rows (perhaps `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`). I'm really not clear on what your problem is based on the description so far. You say you have an array `projID`, do you simply need `projID[row]` to get the string out of it???

Comment: -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    
    NSNumber *myProjectArrayString = [projID objectAtIndex:row];
    //NSNumber *myTaskArrayString = [taskID objectAtIndex:row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",myArrayString);
    //NSLog(@"%@",myTaskArrayString);
    lblProjects.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myProjectArrayString];
    //lblProjects.hidden = YES;
    lblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    //lblTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myTaskArrayString];
    
}